# Create Dataproc cluster with custom image: Failed to resolve image version

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

When trying to create Dataproc cluster with custom image I am getting this ...

```
│ Error: Error creating Dataproc cluster: googleapi: Error 400: Failed to resolve image version 'my-ubuntu18-custom'. Accepted image versions: [preview, 2.0-centos, 1.2-deb9, 1.3-debian9, 1.2-debian9, 1.5-debian10, 1.5-centos8, 2.0-ubuntu18, 1.0-debian9, 1.1-debian9, 1.5-ubuntu18, preview-centos8, preview-debian10, preview-ubuntu18, 2.0-debian, 1.4-debian9, preview-debian, 2.0-debian10, 1.1-debian, 1.0-debian, 1.2-debian, preview-ubuntu, 1.5-centos, 1.3-deb9, 1.4-ubuntu18, 1.5-ubuntu, preview-centos, 1.4-debian10, 1.1-deb9, 1.3-ubuntu, 1.4-ubuntu, 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3-debian10, 1.4, 2.0-ubuntu, 1.5, 1.4-debian, 1.5-debian, 1.0-deb9, 1.3-debian, 1.3-ubuntu18, 2.0-centos8]. See https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-versions for additional information on image versioning., badRequest
```

The custom images list shows the custom image however ...

```
$ gcloud compute images list --no-standard-images | grep NAME:
NAME: my-ubuntu18-custom
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `--image` instead of `--image-version` flag if creating the Dataproc cluster using `gcloud`, and you have to specify the full image URI instead of just the short name.

You can [find the full URI](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-images#using_a_custom_image) by looking for the "selfLink" when getting the full details of the image:

```
gcloud compute images describe my-ubuntu18-custom | grep selfLink
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to standardize the format across both the standard and custom images? That is, use the `https://...` for both? Then we will have to deal with just `image` . Is there `https://...` equivalents for the standard image versions?